# Exporting FolderClientPermission of 40k Public Folders

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, windows-server, public-folders

In an effort to clean the contents of all Public Folders (including mail-enabled folders), I need to generate an export of all the 40.000 Public Folders in our Exchange environment and list its name (Identity), the authorised users (User) and the assigned permissions (AccessRights). I have tried a Microsoft tool called ExFolders and while it succesfully made an export of the permissions of every folder, the formatting was unusable, adding 2 columns for every permission entry. So I looked for a better option with 3 columns in total. Using PowerShell this seems a straightforward action that should be easily achieved with the following script:

```
$PFAll = Get-PublicFolder \ -Recurse -ResultSize Unlimited
$PFClientPermissions = Get-PublicFolderClientPermission $PFAll | Select-Object Identity,@{Expression={$_.User};Label="User";} ,@{Expression={$_.AccessRights};Label="AccessRights";}
$PFClientPermissions | Export-CSV -Path C:\Exports\PublicFolderClientPermission.csv
```

The $PFAll can be succesfully set. When creating $PFClientPermissions, the following error is returned (exceeding data receiving limit in PowerShell):

> Sending date to a remote command failed with the following error message: The current deserialized object size of the data 
>   received from remote client exceeded allowed maximum object size. The current deserialized object size is 78694400. 
>   Allowed maximum object size is 78643200. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (System.Manageme...pressionSyncJob:PSInvokeExpressionSyncJob) [], PSRe
>      motingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure

I hope you can help. Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.

Comment: Do it in chunks. It crossed the max object size which is 78643200. 
But your object size is 78694400.. So try to split it in 2 chunks.

Comment: Thank you Ranadip. How can this be achieved?